# Visual Studio 2015 Solution Explorer not refreshing Git changes upon commit

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a Visual Studio 2015 solution that is under git source control. I have added a new project, committed the new project locally, and synced my commit to the remote repository. All of this has been done through the Visual Studio Git plugin.
However, the Solution Explorer still shows my files as changed or added:

[image]

In the Visual Studio Team Explorer, under 'Changes', nothing is listed. In the 'Synchronization' view, it says 'Successfully synchronized incoming and outgoing commits.'

When I query the local changes through the **git command line**, nothing is listed:

[image]

**Refreshing** the solution in Visual Studio using the refresh button doesn't work either. Only **restarting Visual Studio** fixed the problem.

Any clue on how to fix this?

Comment: Any suggestion ?

Comment: I'm having the same problem with visual studio 2017 on a parallels virtual machine on mac, seems the problem only happens when the solution is on a network drive on the mac side, copying the solution to the windows drive works fine.